# Why is the Verizon Cloud app generating Instabug text files in my File Manager Documents folder every time I start up my phone?

Tags: file-management, media-files

I am getting a lot of text files in my File Manager's Documents folder. I used the Properties option on the file to see that it is an Instabug file. The path shows VCast.

After searching for various terms, I discovered that VCast is from Verizon, which is my carrier. But, I cannot find an App on phone for VCast or any information online about it or why I am getting these text files.

---

Additional information:

After using the online chat option at Verizon I found out this information:

VChat is used in streaming videos and music. I use the Hoopla app to play TV shows. It seems like these text files are generated when I play a TV show.

The Verizon rep I chatted with suggested to scan with an antivirus app. I already use one. I tried another. That didn't work.

---

Additional information:

There were two more text files in my Documents folder this morning. So, this is not resolved. I didn't run any videos or play any music last night or this morning. The text file's date and time were for last night when I had my phone on briefly and for today with the time I started up my phone.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it appears that the culprit app is the VERIZON CLOUD APP.

I went to the Instabug website. I was thinking of actually sending them a message because the path shows their software name. But, I found this article. It appears that Verizon uses Instabug, and the person interviewed for the article is Mohammad Hariri, DMTS for Verizon’s Communications and Cloud division. So, I thought I would try disabling the Verizon Cloud and and IT WORKED!!! I have turned my phone on and off three times. I don't get the text files!

https://instabug.com/customers/verizon

So, now the question is: How can someone in charge of that Verizon Cloud app look at this issue?

Extra: I reinstalled the Verizon Cloud and instantly got a text message in that Documents folder.